# How to filter sub list object in realm using swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I have created two `Realm Object`. I want to filter sub list object but I am not able to filter.

My first object is as below

```
class OrgDetails: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var orgId: Int = 0
     //some other property
    let orgMembers = List<OrgMembers>()
    @objc dynamic var isRemoved: Bool = false
    //other code
}
```

My second object

```
class OrgMembers: Object,Codable {
    @objc dynamic var orgId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var orgMemberId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var isDeleted: Bool = false
    //other property and code
}
```

here I am trying below query to filter the result set. I want to select only those **orgMembers which are not deleted along with it's orgDetails.**

```
let orgs = RealmManager.shared.read(condition: "isRemoved = false", object: OrgDetails.self)?.filter("orgMembers.isDeleted = false")
```

I have also tried this

```
self.corporates = RealmManager.shared.read(condition: "isRemoved == false and orgMembers.isDeleted == false", object: OrgDetails.self)?.toArray(type: OrgDetails.self)
```

But both queries gives an error

```
'Invalid predicate', reason: 'Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations'
```

How can I use filter to fetch records? Is there any other way to achieve above result?

Comment: If an org member is deleted, but the org details it belongs to is not removed, do you want it to be in the results? (It sounds like you don't want it to be in the results, but do realise that you are getting a `Results<OrgDetails>`, so you can only filter the org details, not the org members)

Comment: Are you trying to end up with an array of OrgDetails or an array of OrgMembers? If it's the latter, is it a one dimensional or a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: @rs7 Thanks for reply. Yeah I am trying to get Array of OrgDetails along with OrgMembers.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for reply. The scenario you mentioned in comment will not happed. So here I want to get OrgDetails along with it's OrgMembers which are not deleted.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear but the problem is you cannot return two different objects in a result - they are homogenous. e.g. if your goal is to return *orgs and members which are not deleted* as stated in the question, you can't. You can return orgs, or you can return members but not both. Perhaps you mean you want to query for OrgDetails were isRemoved = false AND has a orgMembers object where isDeleted = false? Might be a good idea to re-think what's being asked and clarify the question.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your reply. I want to fetch only those orgMembers which are not delete. One Org have many OrgMembers. So I want to skip those member having `isDeleted == true`.

Comment: I think you mean fetch OrgDetails as the OrgDetails objects have many OrgMembers in their list. Check out my answer if that's the case. If not, check out the answer anyway and update your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are trying to:
1- Filter the OrgDetails that have isRemove set to false
2- For each element of the array obtained in 1/, you want to filter out the org members and only keep those that are not deleted.

Here is how I would go about it:

```
var orgs = RealmManager.shared.read(condition: "isRemoved = false", object: OrgDetails.self)
orgs.forEach {
   $0.orgMembers = Array($0.orgMembers.filter({ !$0.isDeleted }))
}
```

Comment: @Ajay While this kinda may work, keep in mind it disconnects the objects from Realm so they will no longer be live updating or observable. Also, it will loose the lazily loading aspect of Realm objects and if there are a lot of objects, could overload the devices memory. Also, the results of the filter are unused so not sure what the plan is there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried your code but it is giving an error `Cannot assign value of type 'LazyFilterSequence<List<OrgMembers>>' to type 'List<OrgMembers>'`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

If you want a list of orgs that have not been removed AND that have zero deleted members, this will give you what you want:

```
let orgs = RealmManager.shared.read(condition: "isRemoved == false", object: OrgDetails.self)?
    .filter("SUBQUERY(orgMembers, $orgMember, $orgMember.isDeleted == true).@count == 0")
```

If you want a list of orgs that have not been removed, omitting its members that have been deleted, you can't do that with a query. My suggestion would be to define your OrgDetails model with two lists. One list having members that have not been deleted and another list with deleted members.

```
class OrgDetails: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var orgId: Int = 0
    let orgMembers = List<OrgMembers>()
    let orgMembersDeleted = List<OrgMembers>()
    @objc dynamic var isRemoved: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah I want to fetch only those orgMembers which are not delete. One Org have many OrgMembers. So I want to skip those member having `isDeleted == true` members. I tried your query but it is not return any records. I have one org with multiple orgMembers. Some of them are deleted and others are not.

Comment: The query I gave you will only return orgs that have zero deleted members. So if your org has any deleted members it will not show up in the results. Like I said, you question was a bit unclear. But hopefully this clarifies.

Comment: Oh okay. So is there any way to get only those orgMember which are not deleted?

Comment: Like I said above, you can either have two lists, one for deleted members and one for non-deleted members. Or you can simply filter out deleted members from orgMembers whenever you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Let me restate the question:

> Based on the two Realm objects in the question, you want to return all
> OrgDetails where isRemoved = false AND ANY orgMembers in the list have
> a isRemoved property = false.

In other words if the isRemoved is false on the main property and any orgMembers in the list have isRemoved = false.

If that's the question then the answer is a one liner

```
let result = realm.objects(OrgDetails.self).filter("isRemoved == false AND (ANY orgMembers.isDeleted == false)")
```

This will return all OrgDetails objects where isRemoved is false and any OrgMembers in their List property have isDeleted = false.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried your query but it is deleted orgMembers  as well. I want to skip all deleted OrgMembers and want to only select not deleted members. Basically I want to skip all those who is having `isDeleted == true`

Comment: @Ajay That's exactly what my answer does; returns all OrgDetails objects where isRemoved == false AND where any of the OrgMembers objects isDeleted is false. In other words; suppose the OrgDetails isRemoved property false. That means it's a candidate. Then suppose that OrgDetails has a List property with 10 orgMembers in it. If any one of them has isDeleted set to false then the OrgDetails objects passes the requirements and is returned. If that's NOT what you want, you really need to clarify the question so we can provide an accurate answer based on accurate info.